# Profiling Loading and Unloading of Addressables

Tags: unity, profiling

I've recently set up a small helper class to load and unload addressables, it contains the following methods for that purpose

```
    private IEnumerator LoadObjects<TObject>(IList<object> keys, Addressables.MergeMode mergeMode = Addressables.MergeMode.Union)
    {
            var locations = Addressables.LoadResourceLocationsAsync(keys, mergeMode, typeof(TObject));

            yield return locations;

            var asyncOperationHandles = new List<AsyncOperationHandle>(locations.Result.Count);
            
            foreach (var location in locations.Result)
            {
                    if (_allObjectAsyncOperationHandlesByLocationKey.ContainsKey(location.PrimaryKey))
                    {
                            continue;
                    }
                    
                    var asyncOperationHandle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<TObject>(location);

                    asyncOperationHandle.Completed += obj =>
                    {
                            if (obj.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
                            {
                                    _allObjectAsyncOperationHandlesByLocationKey.Add(location.PrimaryKey, obj);
                                    _allAddressableLocationKeysByObject.Add(obj.Result, location.PrimaryKey);

                                    if (obj.Result is GameObject gameObj) OnGameObjectLoaded?.Invoke(gameObj);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    // TODO: 
                            }
                    };
                    
                    asyncOperationHandles.Add(asyncOperationHandle);
            }

            yield return Addressables.ResourceManager.CreateGenericGroupOperation(asyncOperationHandles, true);
    }
    
    private IEnumerator UnloadObjects(List<object> objs)
    {
            var keys = new List<string>();
            foreach (var obj in objs)
            {
                    if (_allAddressableLocationKeysByObject.ContainsKey(obj))
                    {
                            keys.Add(_allAddressableLocationKeysByObject[obj]);
                    }
            }
            
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                    if (!_allObjectAsyncOperationHandlesByLocationKey.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                            continue;
                    }

                    var asyncOperationHandle = _allObjectAsyncOperationHandlesByLocationKey[key];

                    if (asyncOperationHandle.Result is GameObject gameObj) OnGameObjectUnloaded?.Invoke(gameObj);
                    
                    _allObjectAsyncOperationHandlesByLocationKey.Remove(key);
                    
                    _allAddressableLocationKeysByObject.Remove(asyncOperationHandle.Result);
                    
                    Addressables.Release(asyncOperationHandle);
            }

            yield return true; // Return true only so that this method can be queued as a coroutine (same as loading)
    }
```

Now I've tested to load something and unload it in a similar fashion, I've proofed this with the memory module of the profiler and saw the memory go up when loading and go down the same amount when unloading (in a build).

But now I've coupled this system with an object pool, i.e. as soon as a game object is loaded from an addressable I create a pool for it. The issue now is that I load the resource, I create a pool (i.e. I create game objects via the normal instantiate using the result returned by the operation handle), then when unloading I first delete the pool (f.e. destroying the instantiated game objects) and lastly release the operation handle responsible for the resource. And this seems to kind of work, but the memory doesn't go down the same amount while unloading as when I loaded it, and I don't know how to debug this aspect. I tried with the addressable event view but I don't know what to do with its results. I don't have a screenshot at hand right now, but what I saw was that the resource was loaded (I was able to see the actual prefab), but it was the child of a dependency, and when I unloaded the prefab, it disappeared from the event viewer, but the dependency remained with a ref count of one, which might be the issue of the remaining amount of memory?

My question therefore is, how can I correctly determine if the loading and unloading of addressables is working (and why if not) when not relying on the instantiate async method using the profiler and event viewer?